# foce layout drag and mouse function

Tags: d3.js

I understand the |, &, ~ operators being used but I still can't interpret these functions:

```
function d3_layout_forceDragstart(d) {
    d.fixed |= 2;
}
function d3_layout_forceDragend(d) {
    d.fixed &= ~6;
}
function d3_layout_forceMouseover(d) {
    d.fixed |= 4;
    d.px = d.x, d.py = d.y;
}
function d3_layout_forceMouseout(d) {
    d.fixed &= ~4;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are just setting bit flags with bitwise AND, OR and NOT. If you look in the [d3 source code](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/tree/master/src) their use is documented:

```
// The fixed property has three bits:
// Bit 1 can be set externally (e.g., d.fixed = true) and show persist.
// Bit 2 stores the dragging state, from mousedown to mouseup.
// Bit 3 stores the hover state, from mouseover to mouseout.
// Dragend is a special case: it also clears the hover state.

function d3_layout_forceDragstart(d) {
  d.fixed |= 2; // set bit 2
}

function d3_layout_forceDragend(d) {
  d.fixed &= ~6; // unset bits 2 and 3
}

function d3_layout_forceMouseover(d) {
  d.fixed |= 4; // set bit 3
  d.px = d.x, d.py = d.y; // set velocity to zero
}

function d3_layout_forceMouseout(d) {
  d.fixed &= ~4; // unset bit 3
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks I guess I was looking at an old version I didn't see any comments in there